# VBA Combobox, choose item using 2nd column item

Tags: excel, combobox, userform, vba

I have a UserForm containing ComboBox and items added to it (2 columns). When adding data of invoice I have button to insert data from latest invoice - to save some time.

ComboBox shows user only 1st column items and saving data using 2nd column items. When I want to copy data from last invoice it shows me error using below code. Code tries to select item using 2nd column item.

Is it possible to select proper item in 1 column using 2nd column item?

kraj_dostawcy is ComboBox name

```
kraj_dostawcy.List(kraj_dostawcy.ListIndex, 1) = fak_path.Offset(-1, 5)
```

Comment: What's the error? You appear to be trying to *change* the item in the list, not select it?

Comment: @Rory it says: `381 Could not get the list property. invalid property array index.`. Yes, you may be right... this field was changed from TextBox to ComboBox and now I am trying to fix some issues. Anyway I want to select using 2nd column item. But no clue how to do it...

Comment: Above code was used to get selected item, I thought same way it can select what I want...

Comment: Your code is trying to write the selected value of the cell to the control, not the other way round.

Comment: So in other words I should make a loop to check all values from ComboBox with my `fak_path.offsert(-1,5).value` and if true select this item? I thought there is easier way...

Comment: If the bound column is the one containing that value, you should just be able to assign the cell value to the Value of the combobox, not to its List property.

Comment: @Rory, that's excacly what I wanted. ComboBox.BoundColumn property. Please write down your anwser so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the control's BoundColumn property to set the column containing the values you want returned from it, you can just assign the cell value to the Value of the combobox, not to its List property.